# JPA: Id column settable both automatically and manually

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I'm using MySQL and have the following entity:

```
class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
}
```

However, I would still like to be able to set the id manually!

The problem is that INSERT will never insert the id column. E.g., when
doing this:

```
MyEntity e = new MyEntity();
e.setId(15);
em.persist(e);
em.flush();
em.refresh(e);
```

The following queries will be made:

```
INSERT INTO myEntities (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
SELECT id, col1, col2, col3 FROM myEntities WHERE (id = 15)
```

And thus the id will still be auto-generated and the `refresh()` will
result in `EntityNotFoundException`.

If I don't set `@GeneratedValue` at all, then this case will work OK,
but when the value is autogenerated, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` won't be called.

Is it at all possible to have id columns settable both manually and
automatically, like in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With EclipseLink, manually assigning ids will work for TABLE based sequencing and SEQUENCE object sequencing but not with IDENTITY.

Answer (score 2):

JPA doesn't cater for that scenario (nor does JDO either); it assumes you either set the id yourself, or you generate it using the provided generators.
[DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform) has an extension by adding 
@Extension(key="strategy-when-notnull", value="true")
which will generate the value when you didn't set the "id" value, and use your value if you provided it. Maybe other implementations allow something similar ?

--Andy (DataNucleus)

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. Do you know if there are any plans to change this in JPA 2?